# Probability of Finding Oil

Tags: probability

> An oil prospector will drill a succession of holes in a given area until he finds r productive wells. The probability that he is successful on a given trial is 0.3. The prospector can only afford to drill 6 wells. What is the probability the inspector fails to find r productive wells if:
>
> (a) r = 1? (b) r = 2? (c) r = 3?

I believe I did the work correctly I just want some clarification.

Let S=sucuess and F=Failure.  So $P(S)=.3$ and $P(F)=.7$.  So to find each we would have to do a geometric disturbution, $p(r)=P(F)^{6-r}P(S)$

So for a, we have: $p(r=1)=(.7)^{6-1}(.3)=.050421$

For b: $p(r=2)=(.7)^{6-2}(.3)=.07203$

And for c: $p(r=3)=(.7)^{6-3}(.3)=.1029$

Comment: You are writing that the probability is greater to find more productive wells. Or if you prefer, it's easier to find $3$ than a single one. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Important: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: What do you mean by that @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: It's supposed to be a sanity check. When giving a numerical result, always check if it's at least plausible. You are writing that it's more difficult (the probability of success is smaller), to find one productive well, than to find $3$ of them. But if he has found $3$, he has of course already found one, so, if he were to stop after the first, that would mean the probability to find one should be at least as large, not smaller.

Comment: There is another problem, with notation: writing $p(r=1)$, $p(r=2)$, $p(r=3)$ seems to suggest $r$ is a random variable, but it's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of success for a given $r$ is the probability to have at least $r$ successes when attempting $6$ times an expriment with a probability of success equal to $p=0.3$.

That is, if $X$ is random variable following a binomial ditribution $B(6,0.3)$, the probability $p_r$ of success, for a given $r$, is

$$p_r=p(X\ge r)$$

Since $X\ge r+1\implies X\ge r$, this also means that $p_{r+1}\le p_{r}$, that is $p_r$ is decreasing as $r$ increases.

Now,

$$p_1=p(X\ge1)=1-p(X=0)=1-(1-p)^6\simeq0.882351$$

$$p_2=p(X\ge2)=1-p(X\le1)=1-(1-p)^6-\binom{6}{1}p(1-p)^5\simeq0.579825$$

$$p_3=p(X\ge3)=1-p(X\le2)=1-(1-p)^6-\binom{6}{1}p(1-p)^5-\binom{6}{2}p^2(1-p)^4\simeq0.25569$$

It may look like we are cheating, since the guy is supposed to stop when he reaches $r$ successes. But we can pretend he then continues to drill until he reaches $6$, as this won't change the outcome. That's why we must check if $X$ is *at least* $r$.